Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator in Flutter
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(HomePage());

class Root extends StatelessWidget {
  const Root({ Key ? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.lightBlue),
      home: HomePage(),
      routes: {
        'settings': (context) => Settings()
      }
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: Localizations(
        locale: const Locale('en', 'US'),
        delegates: const <LocalizationsDelegate<dynamic>>[
          DefaultWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          DefaultMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,

            appBar: AppBar(
              body: Center(
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      NavigationButton('Settings', Icons.settings, 'settings')
                    ]
                )
              )
        )
      )
    );
  }

  Widget NavigationButton(String label, IconData icon, String route) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, route),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Icon(icon),
          const SizedBox(width: button_sized_box_width),
          Text(label)
        ]
      )
    );
  }
}

When I press the NavigationButton, it gives an error: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator, in Flutter. Nothing solved this problem. I tried wrapping the app with a builder etc.
I read the answers in StackOverflow, they say you shouldn't put this into the same level as MaterialPage() widget and so on but nothing solved this problem.

You are adding a HomePage widget in runApp and routes are configured in the Root widget, because of this Navigator is not available in your context.  Please add Root to your runApp everything will work fine.

try this:
void main() => runApp(Root());
 // Changed from HomePage to Root to ensure MaterialApp is the root widget

let me know if it helped

Wow, I missed a such small point. Thank you very much.
